# SPA user login with AWS JS sdk for Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-js, amazon-cognito-identity-js

I'm trying to implement user login with username and password on a spa using aws cognito, but I keep getting error on the auth flow.

Previously I was using ['amazon-cognito-identity-js'](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js) and it was all ok, but I'm moving to ['@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider'](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/index.html) and now I can't even login my user.

From web console I can see that Cognito app client enabled auth flows are

- `ALLOW_REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH`
- `ALLOW_CUSTOM_AUTH`
- `ALLOW_USER_SRP_AUTH`.

I tried almost every [`AuthFlowType`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/enums/authflowtype.html) value but browser console logs following error or ask for additional required params based on the auth flow tested.

##### Browser console log error

```
Uncaught (in promise) InvalidParameterException: Initiate Auth method not supported.
```

##### Login command code:

```js
 command = new AdminInitiateAuthCommand({
     ClientId: AWS_COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_ID,
     UserPoolId: AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
     AuthFlow: AuthFlowType.<WHAT_VALUE_TO_INSERT_?>,
     AuthParameters: {
         USERNAME: username,
         PASSWORD: password
     }
});
```

#### Update#1

I added the `ALLOW_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH` flag to the allowed auth flows for the app client from the web console and used the `AuthFlowType.USER_PASSWORD_AUTH` value to login, but still I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Did you mean to use AdminInitiateAuthCommand which initiates the authentication flow as an administrator instead of InitiateAuthCommand which initiates sign-in for a user?

Comment: @jarmod you're right, what I need is `InitiateAuthCommand` and not `AdminInitiateAuthCommand`. I couldn't find any good example/tutorial and going by trial and error I mistakenly ended up using the wrong class. Do you know where to find some docs/examples?

Comment: Possible example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72679431/users-unable-to-authenticate-with-their-email-and-password-with-aws-cognito) but also be aware of this [example](https://kelvinmwinuka.com/basic-authentication-with-aws-cognito-and-nextjs) that does use AdminInitiateAuthCommand (if you eventually do need that).

Answer (score 1):

An option that works for SPA is to use the Amplify Libraries, it has an Authentication API which abstracts the logic to call Cognito user pools to authenticate. You can configure the Amplify Authentication library as per this link:

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/start/q/platform/js/#re-use-existing-authentication-resource

After that you can sign in using the Auth.signIn method:
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/emailpassword/q/platform/js/#sign-in